# How to get a string and check for some specific characters?

Tags: c#, string, chars

i want check string chars from the start and get specific symbols:

Example:

String Text = "http://www.MyWeb.com/24172-cool.html"

should be like that: are Text from the start equal with "http://www.MyWeb.com/"
and later check are after last slash it is numbers and after numbers is symbol -
and later if everything is correct, how get these numbers to string? Because numbers can be 24172 or just 121, or 1, or 2000000.

I have no idea how to do that, maybe somebody can help me? Explain that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression such as `http:\/\/.+\/([0-9]+)-.*`  You can quickly create and test them using a [Regular Expression Playground](http://www.regexr.com/).